# Apple software - Numbers

Tags: macbook-pro, numbers, iwork

How do I identify and add(sum) only specific cells in a row - they are not continuous cells. Ex. I1, O1, U1 total sum and show in BG1

Comment: Could you edit this to show what you have so far? A screen shot and your best attempt at a formula might be a good place to start. Also, what version of OS X and numbers is in play here.

Answer (score 2):

You would use a formula for this.  In the cell you want the SUM to display (BG1 in your question), enter this formula
`=SUM(I1,O1,U1)`

Note that the function is `SUM()` preceded by an equal sign `=` and the cell values are comma separated. You can also include ranges by putting a colon between cells.  Say you wanted to select A1 through E1, then I1, O1, and U1:
`=SUM(A1:E1,I1,O1,U1)`

Here is a list containing some of the functions available to you in Numbers.  [Apple - Numbers - Functions](http://www.apple.com/mac/numbers/compatibility/functions.html)